# "Безусловно" и "конечно" - оба в одном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, части-речи

Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, чтобы "безусловно, конечно" были вместе в одном предложении.
Чем они будут являться? Какими частями речи?

Comment: Это — домашнее задание сообществу?

Answer (score 4):

***Такое невезение, безусловно, конечно.***

Безусловно - вводное слово, конечно - краткое прилагательное в роли сказуемого.

***Моё решение безусловно, конечно***.

Безусловно - краткое прилагательное, выполняет роль сказуемого; конечно - вводное слово.

***Приму решение безусловно, конечно.***

Безусловно - наречие, является обстоятельством; конечно - вводное слово.

***Да, так и будет, безусловно, конечно!*** (в разговорном стиле)

Безусловно и конечно - вводные слова.

Comment: Какие замечательные примеры - первые три. Мне даже в голову не приходило, что можно так вывернуть семантику и грамматическую роль. ))) Да вот боюсь, что вопрос-то только о значениях последнего примера, когда оба слова - вводные... И вот тут непонятно, это как усиление? Запятую можно на союз "И" заменить? Иначе или смысл размывается - или тавтология имеет место...

Comment: Согласна с Вами и признаю, что предложения примитивны и надуманны. Просто хотелось решить задачку. В последнем примере действительно предполагается усиление. Правда, лучше было бы в этом случае поменять слова местами: конечно, безусловно. Союз, мне кажется, можно вставить.

Comment: *предложения примитивны и надуманны* @ЕкатеринаКаштанова, я совсем не это хотел сказать. Мне действительно понравилось - как образец нестандартного подхода. А вот последний пример - именно тот, в который, как я понимаю и заключен подразумеваемый смысл вопроса - он не совсем понятен без разъяснений.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо Вам, я надеялась на такой ответ!)))

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, пока еще трудно сделать безусловно правильный вывод, но общий подход к проблеме, я думаю, верен.

Здесь *конечно* – вводное слово, а *безусловно* – наречие в роли обстоятельства.